# How to get a line from csv file with a custom fgets

Tags: c, csv

I'm currently writing a program in C that reads in from a CSV file, I have a defined buffer size but am having trouble separating each line from the buffer. I can see where the line ends by checking for a '\n' char. I cannot extract that line from the buffer for parsing however. Anybody have some ideas?

```
#ifndef BUFFSIZE
   #define BUFFSIZE 4096
#endif

int main() {
  int fd;
  int fdBin;
  char * buf = malloc(BUFFSIZE);
  int count = 0;

  bool EOFFlag = false;

  fd = open("SongCSV.csv", O_RDONLY);
  fdBin = open("BinarySongData.bin", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, "0600");
  if (fd == -1) {
    printf("failed to open a file\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  off_t offset = 0;
  off_t offsetOld = 0;

  int readBytes;

  while (!EOFFlag) {
    offsetOld = offset;
    offset = lseek(fd, offset - offsetOld, SEEK_CUR);

    readBytes = read(fd, buf, BUFFSIZE);

    printf("\n\n%lld\n\n", (offset));
    int i = 0;
    int commaCounter = 0;
    while (i < readBytes) {
      if (buf[i] != '\n') {

      }

      if (buf[i] == '\n') {
        printf("\t\t THIS IS END OF LINE \t%d", i);
        commaCounter = 0;

      }

      if (buf[i] == ',') {
        commaCounter++;
        if (commaCounter == 4) {
          printf("****Album Name****");
        }
      }
      write(fdBin, buf, BUFFSIZE);
      printf("%c", buf[i]);
      i++;
    }
    if (readBytes < BUFFSIZE) {
      EOFFlag = true;
      printf("\nREACHED END OF FILE");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("AA: END OF LINE ****%d*****", count);

    count++;
  }

  close(fd);
  close(fdBin);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not using `fopen` & `fgets` ?

Comment: The assignment I have for school prohibits the use for 'F' functions

Comment: don't you think it's important to mention this in your question?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to edit it now

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why are you writing the buffer to your output file each iteration? Is the CSV just one line or do you have to select a line from multiple lines?

Comment: So I pull in more than one line with my buffer size. Where buf[i] == '\n' that indicates the end of 1 line. I want to get an individual line out of that buffer.

Comment: Why not create a `char linebuf[BUFFSIZE];` and `int index = 0;` then reorder your `if` statements `if (buf[i] == '\n') { /* nul-terminate linebuf, use it, reset index */ } else { if (buf[i] == ',') { /* handle field */ }; linebuf[index++] = buf[i]; }` or something similar so you check for `'\n'` use `linebuf` and reset `index`, otherwise you are filling `linebuf` while checking for commas?

Comment: My plan was to just read in each line into a buffer and then use strsep() to parse the line. I'm just not sure how to get that line dynamically

Comment: The problem is you can have a partial line in one `BUFFSIZE` worth of characters and then the rest of the line in the next. You need a separate buffer to collected all the characters in the line before you use it.

Comment: regarding: `write(fdBin, buf, BUFFSIZE);  there is no guarantee that `BUFFSIZE` bytes were read by the call to `read()`.  However, the returned value from that call: `readbytes` is the number of bytes actually read.  Suggest: `write(fdBin, buf, readbytes);`  Also, the code should be checking the returned value from the call to `write()` and use a 'sliding window' in a loop until all the bytes are actually written to the new file.

Comment: it is 11 hours since the OP stated they were going to edit the question.  The indicated edit is still not done.

Comment: a call to `printf()` is 'expensive'.  for this statement: `printf("%c", buf[i]);` suggest using: `putc( buff[i], stdout );`

Comment: regarding: `if (readBytes < BUFFSIZE) {
      EOFFlag = true;`  what happens if the input file size is exactly a multiple of BUFFSIZE?

Comment: the posted code is failing to handle any I/O error from `read()` and `write()`

Comment: why bother with `lseek()`?  Especially when using '.., 0, SEEK_CUR' There is nothing in the code that is making any real use of the function.

Comment: It was edited over again, but I need to keep a pointer to go back if the line gets cut off from the buffer. I still can't get a single line from what I read into my buffer

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way, easy and simple. I just did it quickly, any doubts just ask me, Cheers.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  int len = sending();
  char *firstline;
  int i = 0;
  char buf[0];
  int rd ;
  int fd = open("hey.csv", O_RDONLY);

  rd = read(fd, buf, 1);    
  firstline = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
  while (i != len)
    {
      firstline[i] = buf[0];
      i++;
      rd = read(fd, buf, 1);
    }
  firstline[i] = '\0';
  printf("%s\n", firstline);
  return (0);
}

int sending()
{
  int fd = open("hey.csv", O_RDONLY);
  char buf[1];
  int r = 0;
  r = read(fd, buf, 1);
  int len = 0;

  while (buf[0] != '\n')//getting exact size to malloc
    {
      len++;
      r = read(fd, buf, 1);    

    }
  return len;
}
```